# Combining rows based on Job ID in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

New to SQL working with SQL Server. I have a query that pulls all the information we need to perform analysis on a group of clients but based on how the system is set up it currently requires manual clean up in excel before the data becomes useful.

Some Job ID's end with S but when when we do analysis we look at the Job ID as a whole and have to spend a lot of time in excel manually combining the data together.

Example query result

```
JOB ID   LABOR EXPENSE  DIRECT MATERIAL
10067    400395.29      96614.25
10067S   143668         44148.22
10068    545100.79      127143.64
10068S   147009.89      33506.31
```

What I would like to do is when the query is run combine the rows with the S in the `Job ID` into the ones without so we just get one line of data for each job.

Example

```
Job ID  LABOR EXPENSE   DIRECT MATERIAL
10067   544063.29       140762.47
10068   692110.68       160649.95
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can alter my query to accomplish this?

Comment: Is `JobId` always a number possibly followed by an "S"?  I should also note that this is pretty easy to do in Excel with pivot tables, but that is another matter.

Comment: Sometimes they are followed by 'ICE' or 'LEAK' depending on the job. Sometimes we will have the original job followed by all three sub jobs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select replace( Job_Id, 'S', '' ) as "JOB ID",
       sum (LABOR_EXPENSE) as "LABOR EXPENSE",
       sum (DIRECT_MATERIAL) as "DIRECT MATERIAL"
  from yourTable
group by replace( Job_Id, 'S', '' )
order by replace( Job_Id, 'S', '' )
```

Remember to change the columns accordingly since it may not be defined with spaces or even as I suggested with underlines.

Comment: Thank you Jorge! This worked perfect! If I wanted to alter the SQL statement to also perform the replace on jobs that end in 'ICE' and 'LEAK' how would I do that?

Comment: you could then use `regexp_replace` function like: `regexp_replace( Job_Id, 'S|ICE|LEAK', '' )` it receives a regular expression in your case it would be: `'S|ICE|LEAK'` which means **S or ICE or LEAK** but regexes functions perform bad in a great amount of data

Comment: The alternative would be replace within replace like `replace( replace( replace( Job_Id, 'S', '' ), 'ICE', '' ), 'LEAK', '' )` but this is not as elegant as a regex :)

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

A variation on a theme that works (if your id values consistent of numbers of consistent digit length) is to use substring:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(job_id,1,5) AS job_no, 
SUM(labor_exp) AS tot_lab,
SUM(direct_mat) AS tot_mat
FROM jobs
GROUP BY SUBSTRING(job_id,1,5)
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72838/16

Comment: Since it is an id is most likely would differ in size, so you could use in your substring version from 1 to the "s" char minus one :)

Comment: Thank you Stidgeon! This worked great as well. It also helped account for the Job #'s that end in 'ICE' or 'LEAK' instead of 'S'. I just need to perform an analysis and see if I have any Job ID's that are more or less than 5 characters long.